# Custom Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

My collection looks like this

[image]

I need to get all those order no's whose Pick's SeqNo is Greater than whose Deliver Status. Business rule is these operations happen based on their SeqNo and no Order No should deliver before get picked up.

In given example, i should get Order No 2, because it delivers before it get pickedup.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? And what's the definition of the class whose instances your collection consists of?

Comment: My class has just these 3 properties and upto now i doing this by using foreach loop and a List

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like this - I've separated out the query parts to make it easier to read:

```
var pickups = orders.Where(order => order.Status == Status.Pick);
var deliveries = orders.Where(order => order.Status == order.Deliver);
var query = from pickup in pickups
            join delivery in deliveries on pickup.OrderId equals delivery.OrderId
            where pickup.SeqNo > delivery.SeqNo
            select pickup.OrderId;
```

Comment: Very Simple Solution, BIG THANKS